# How can I set database reference to child of child of order in mentioned image ? Or how can i get the value vehicle name

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

This my FireBase structure. how can I make database reference set to a child of a child of order or get the value of vehicle name, from location and to location and display it in card view Recyclerview?

Comment: Can you share what have you already done?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `ved_nam` property is the vehicle name and the `order` node is a direct child of your Firebase root, to log all your vehicle names, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference orderIdRef = rootRef.child("order").child(orderId);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String ved_nam = ds.child("ved_nam").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", ved_nam);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
orderIdRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

In which the `orderId` is the id of the order that you are looking for (i.e. `ACSIenh9E6WYiLJWAyn1icsHlzr2`).